# How to enter Barcode in series without touching anything else?

Tags: devexpress

The grid has 6 columns, the first column is the bar code, the second is quantity.
Grid has NewItemRow at the top, I need the grid to validate the column barcode if it is valid, fill the following columns.
If a barcode already exists, increase the enter code hereamount.
I want to enter the barcodes in series, without touching anything.
The barcode device sends barcodes in format (code +  enterkey), but it is also possible to use the format (code +  below).

- barcode1 + enter
- barcode2 + enter
- barcode3 + enter

Comment: I would advice to add some code you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Follow the **Minimal, Complete and Verifiable** format for posting any queries. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve